# Differentiating symbolically then obtaining a numerical value

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

```
syms x
syms y

f = 2*x^2 + y
z = diff(f,x)

x = 3
SolvedDiffEq = z
```

Obviously z = 4x.  But how do I solve to get the numerical answer of 12?  I've played with vpa, double, subs and cannot figure it out.

This is a simple example.  My actual code has very complex equations with many variables.  Furthermore, I am trying to iteratively solve these equations so it is not practical to manually substitute each variable.

Comment: When possible, always put the language tag; otherwise your question will hardly be seen by anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [symbolic substitution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) command, which is `subs`. In your example, `subs(z)` returns 12.